# Git not able to commit due to "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten"

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm struggling to get a branch merged into my master branch in Visual Studio 2019. I created a branch from my master, made changes, and now I'm trying to get it merged back into the master branch. Initially I couldn't get it to even switch from the feature branch over to master due to it asking me to commit changes even though everything showed 0 changes or stash. I tried a handful of changes and was eventually able to commit the file in the feature branch which I'm pretty sure was the .suo file. That allowed me to then switch over to the master branch.

Then I went to the Git/Manager Branches section and tried to merge the feature branch into the master. I keep getting an error `Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by the merge: .vs/ProjectName/v16/.suo`

I'm not even sure why it's trying to commit that since I have a .gitignore file made through Visual Studio and I can see the `.vs` folder as part of that file.

I can't seem to commit or stash the file as the Git section in Visual Studio keeps showing `0 outgoing/0 incoming` changes as well as the message `There are no unstaged changes in the working directory.`

Any suggestions on how I can get past this and/or why it keeps trying to track anything in the .vs folder when that is part of my gitignore file?

Answer (score 0):

> commit the file in the feature branch which I'm pretty sure was the .suo file.

You committed the file in the feature branch. Now it's a part of the branch and cannot be ignored — `.gitignore` doesn't ignore committed files.

On the other hand it's not committed in `master` branch so it's ignored and its changes cannot be committed or stashed. So when you merge `git` refuses to merge a committed file with a modified ignored file.

The most correct thing is to remove the file from the feature branch:

```
git checkout feature
git rm -r --cached .vs/ProjectName/v16/.suo
git commit -m "Remove mistakenly committed .vs/ProjectName/v16/.suo"
git checkout master
git merge feature
```

But please be warned next time you checkout the feature branch the file will be removed from `.vs/ProjectName/v16/` because `git` remembers you removed it from the branch.